# How do I add checked item(s) in my checkedlistbox to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, checkedlistbox

I have a dropdownlist that selects category list from Database and display the product name onto the checkedlistbox.  But how do I grabs the checked items from the checkedlistbox to the DataGridView?  This is how my design looks like:

[image: Winform design]

Also, how do I make every medication that has been added to the Gridview has a default value of 1 Quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your Add button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[i], "1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That box isn't a ListView, it's CheckedListBox.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I've edited my answer to work with CheckListBox.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
          }
```