# c# CheckedListbox values

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox

When I want to put the values in an array that are selected from a checkedlistbox. And then say:

> messagebox.show(values[0]);

It's saying : System.Data.DataRowView

This is my current code:

```
        string[] itemArr = new string[clbTables.CheckedItems.Count];
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (object item in this.clbTables.CheckedItems)
        {
            string temp = Convert.ToString(item);
            itemArr[counter] = temp;
            counter++;
        }
        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, itemArr[0].ToString());
```

What am I doing wrong here>?

EDIT ::

```
clbTables.DataSource = sqlDisplayContent.connectDataTable("SELECT ('Tafelnr: '+ CONVERT(varchar,tafelnr)+' Zitplaatsen: '+ CONVERT(varchar,zitPlaatsen)) AS dispValue,tafelnr  FROM tabel");
clbTables.DisplayMember = "dispValue";
clbTables.ValueMember = "tafelnr";



class sqlDisplayContent
        {
            public static DataTable connectDataTable(string query)
            {
                SqlCommand comm= sqlCrud.returnSqlCommand(query);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }

Thankss
```

Comment: I don't see `messagebox.show(values[0]);` in your code...

Comment: you are returning the whole object as item (not the objects text value)

Comment: There is a nice example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: item is a System.Data.DataRowView   and ToString() is System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: You should change `object item in this.clbTables.CheckedItems` to `var item in this.clbTables.CheckedItems`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting System.Data.DataRowView while getting value from ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372464/getting-system-data-datarowview-while-getting-value-from-combobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that:

```
Convert.ToString(item);
```

will simply call the ToString() method of the object and store that, which in this case, is giving you the object's type. In this case, the type is System.Data.DataRowView. I suggest that you access the specific field in the row that you want by using:

```
((DataRowView)item).Row["FieldName"].ToString();
```

instead. You will want to replace "FieldName" with whatever the name of your column that you are wanting is. Additionally, you can use an int index instead of a string reference. Of course, if you need to access multiple fields, you can do this by simple string concatenation. The issue is that you need to access the specific field that you want. Not the entire row as you are currently on.

I hope this helps!

A couple references: [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx), [DataRowView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Okay. That was my fault. I was under the impression that checkedItems would be a collection of the rows. I did some more research, and instead of saying `item.Row["FieldName"].ToString()`, try `((DataRowView)item).Row.Item["FieldName"].ToString();`. You will want to replace "FieldName" with whatever the name of your column that you are wanting is. Additionally, you can use an int index instead. References: [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx), [DataRowView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I apologize for the problems. Try `((DataRowView)item).Row["FieldName"].ToString();`. If this doesn't work, I will delete my post to keep from bothering you with any more incorrect answers.

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm just glad we got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your values[] array is not right. Please, refer to this example on MSDN.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string temp = ((CheckBox)item).Text;
```

You are passing in the object, not the object's text (which is what it seems you want the code to do).

Comment: When I do this it's telling me:"Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'."

Comment: @Jamie, OH! Ok, can you update your code to show us where the CheckedListBox is being implemented into the DataGrid?

Comment: @Jamie, I've found some code here in SO that you may be able to use to get the object that contains the text. I'm unsure of how to get the Text, but it should be simple enough through Visual Studio to show you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450681/how-do-i-add-checked-items-in-my-checkedlistbox-to-a-datagridview

Comment: Thanks but that's just the problem... I can't get the text from the object. It's saying: "System.Data.DataRowView".

Comment: Ok, so you have a checkedlistbox within each data row? If that is the case, then you need to loop each row, loop each checked item in the checkedlistbox, then add each checkbox's text to your string array. That might be the missing step. @Jamie